# PHP MySQL: Select column with title like year

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table ('`contas`') has columns that correspond to years (`2014, 2015, etc...`) among other columns, like:

```
id   | name   | notes   |   2014   | 2015   | 2016
1    | abc    | whatever|   5.25   |  8.50  | 9.50
```

I want to use PHP to select the column that corresponds to the current year from that table.

I have:

```
$ano=date('Y');
$ano=(string)$ano;

$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `notes`, $ano AS 'saldo' FROM `contas` WHERE ..."; 

$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

In the column '`saldo`' I'm getting `2014` for every row, instead of the values of the table.

I tried inserting `$ano` into single and double quotes in the query, but it didn't work.

Comment: and what does `$ano` contain?

Comment: It contains numbers with two decimals (currencies)

Comment: You are saving current year to $ano right?

Comment: Yes, I tested echo ($ano) and got 2014

Comment: What is role of @ano variable here?

Comment: What's the name of the field that contains the year?

Comment: You are selecting 2014 as "saldo" and you are wondering why it is 2014? I am guessing that your var $ano should be better used in a where clause and just select whatever in have in the database as `saldo`

Comment: Your are getting what you are supposed to. Query you send to the server, after the variable replacement is `SELECT `id`, `name`, `notes`, 2014 AS 'saldo' FROM `contas` WHERE ...`

Comment: $ano corresponds to the current year. So, this year it should pick column '2014' from the table.

Comment: Can you avoid this line: $ano=(string)$ano; and check once the query is executing or not

Comment: If you want column named 2014, you should use "`$ano`" (surrounded by backticks)

Comment: @Jenz: I get the same result. Instead of 5.25 I get 2014

Comment: Please see my edit above

Comment: @NunoNogueira Put here errors please.

Comment: What works is changing the column titles to include a letter. So, instead of 2014, 2015, etc..., if I use s2014, s2015, etc.. it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Escape the column name..

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `notes`, `$ano` AS 'saldo' FROM `contas` WHERE ...";
```

Comment: I get exactly the same result: instead of the value 5.25, I get '2014' in the results

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$ano=date('Y');

$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `notes`,`".$ano."` AS 'saldo' FROM `contas` WHERE ...";
```